# React Native TouchableOpacity not updating styles

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity, touchablehighlight

I have a strange issue with the `TouchableOpacity` component. I have a `MainButton` component which takes 2 props, `item` and `disabled`. Based on the the `disabled` prop I want my MainButton component to apply a different style. The problem is when the `TouchableOpacity` component re renders, it does not refresh the style. The prop `disabled` is correctly set on re render.

What makes this strange is that if i change it to a `TouchableHeighlight` it works as expected.

Does anyone know why? Is this a bug in TouchableOpacity?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import UI from '../styles/ui'

import {
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native'

const ui = new UI()
const styles = ui.styles

class MainButton extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      disabled : props.disabled,
      item: props.item
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.setState({disabled:props.disabled})
  }

  render() {
    var normalStyles = [styles.mainButton,styles.widthEighty]
    var disabledStyle = [styles.mainButton,styles.widthEighty,styles.lowOpacity]
    var correctStyles = this.state.disabled ? disabledStyle : normalStyles
    console.log(this.state.disabled,'this.state.disabled ? ');
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity disabled={this.state.disabled} style={correctStyles} accessibilityLabel={this.state.item.name} onPress={this.state.item.onPress.bind(this)}>
        <Text style={styles.mediumLabel}>{this.state.item.name}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

export { MainButton as default }
```

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I wonder if it has something to do with TouchableOpacity [wrapping its children in an Animated.View](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html)? The animation not finishing in time or something? The docs don't mention TouchableHighlight doing similar wrapping but haven't dug into the source to check! Either way, thanks for the TouchableHighlight tip!

Comment: I had the same issue, thanks for the highlight tip it worked

Comment: Did you found solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you use **opacity** style (which using by TouchableOpacity), you should set this style for children of TouchableOpacity (ex a View) like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  disabled={disabled}
  accessibilityLabel={name}
  onPress={onPress}
>
  <View style={disabled ? disabledStyle : normalStyle}>
    <Text style={styles.mediumLabel}>{name}</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think pass the `disabled` and `item` props to state.
You can directly do it in this way and get rid of constructor as well as `componentWillReceiveProps`.
`componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method will be deprecated soon, so they don't encourage its usage.

Also if possible, separate event handler from `item` props.
It's not best way to do that

```
render () {
  const { disabled, item, onPress } = this.props;
  const { name } = item;
  ...
  return (
    ...
    <TouchableOpacity
      disabled={disabled}
      style={disabled ? disabledStyle : normalStyle}
      accessibilityLabel={name}
      onPress={onPress}
    >
      <Text style={styles.mediumLabel}>{name}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    ...
  ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I came up with is to use

`setOpacityTo(value)` in order to update the canvas.

I did this `componentDidUpdate()` as this lifecycle method get's called whenever your new style has been applied within your component. So I gave the `<TouchableOpacity/>` component a `ref` and updated it whenever it's style did change.

**Example:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import UI from '../styles/ui'

import {
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native'

const ui = new UI()
const styles = ui.styles

class MainButton extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      disabled : props.disabled,
      item: props.item
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.setState({disabled:props.disabled})
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.refs['touchable'].setOpacityTo(1.0);
  }

  render() {
    var normalStyles = [styles.mainButton,styles.widthEighty]
    var disabledStyle = [styles.mainButton,styles.widthEighty,styles.lowOpacity]
    var correctStyles = this.state.disabled ? disabledStyle : normalStyles
    console.log(this.state.disabled,'this.state.disabled ? ');
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity ref={'touchable'} disabled={this.state.disabled} style={correctStyles} accessibilityLabel={this.state.item.name} onPress={this.state.item.onPress.bind(this)}>
        <Text style={styles.mediumLabel}>{this.state.item.name}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

export { MainButton as default }
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have enough context to understand exactly what you try to achieve here but try this:

```
  <TouchableOpacity disabled={this.state.disabled} style={this.state.disabled ? disabledStyle : normalStyles} accessibilityLabel={this.state.item.name} onPress={this.state.item.onPress.bind(this)}>
    <Text style={styles.mediumLabel}>{this.state.item.name}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

There is also not enough context on what 'this.state.item.onPress' do, or why you use an item you pass in the props in order to change the props on the first place. It sounds like you can improve the way you implemented this, if you give me more context I might be able to help.